# Does a cofactor of an elliptic curve have to be an integer?

Tags: elliptic-curves

What are the implications of a curve having a non-integer co-factor for its generator point? Is that even possible?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "non-integer". If you have a rational like $\frac{2}{3}$, then that's possible ( if the inverse element exist, that's just a hidden inteder, because $3^{-1}$ is not a fraction but another integer). If you have a irrational number, then no.

Comment: tylo, very good point. I'd give you an upvote if you made an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implications are that someone screwed up some calculation.

By [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), the co-factor must be an integer.